# Why do I have such a large performance difference between a Console app and WinForms?

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, console-application, performance-testing

I wrote some simple C# code to test if a number is a prime. I was surprised to see that there was a huge difference in performance when I ran the code in a WinForms app vs a console app.

The code is pretty simple:

```
ulong num = 18446744073709551557;
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
if (num % 2 == 0)
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("Composite " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    return;
}
for (ulong i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(num); i += 2)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Composite " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
stopwatch.Stop();
MessageBox.Show("Prime " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

For the console app, instead of `MessageBox.Show()`, I use `Console.WriteLine()`. Now I would have thought the performance difference would be negligible. However, the console app seems to consistently perform worse than the windows form app.

Compiled by Visual Studio 2022, for the debug build (run without debugging), it takes ~36000 milliseconds for the winforms app, but ~156000 ms for the console app. For the release build (run without debugging), ~35500 ms for winforms and ~137000 ms for the console. (Interestingly, both seem to run slightly faster if run *with* debugging.) What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: For such benchmarks, you have to use `BenchmarkDotNet`, `StopWatch` is not accurate for microbenchmarks.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Ah, okay, I'll try that when I get time. However, I really doubt it would be inaccurate enough to produce such large differences, so I guess the question still stands.

Comment: I recommend doing a burn-in first, where you spool up the CPU but not time and then start timing.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Hmmm... good idea. Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but what would be a good way to do the "burn in" so that it doesn't just get optimized out by the compiler?

Comment: Also missing here is the platform configuration (x86, AnyCPU, x64), framework version, etc, etc. I noticed the AnyCPU time is 10× the x64 time for my CPU for the above code. Also make sure you run release only, and you start either outside VS studio or run without the debugging (Ctrl-F5).

Comment: I'm confused about what you are actually testing. The `if` is only a handful of CPU instructions and almost impossible to time accurately on a single run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I could not reproduce the issue**.

Here is a summary of my findings running in release, and without the debugger (Ctrl-F5 in VS). Significant differences between 32-bit and 64-bit processes exist for both Console and WinForms.

| IDE | Platform | Console | WinForms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VS2017/NET 4.8 | x32 | 43.94 sec | 43.21 sec |
| VS2017/NET 4.8 | x64 | 4.43 sec | 4.38 sec |
| VS2022/NET 4.8 | x32 | 43.62 sec | 43.33 sec |
| VS2022/NET 4.8 | x64 | 4.56 sec | 4.45 sec |
| VS2022/NET 6.0 | x64 | 4.46 sec | 4.45 sec |

NOTE: The differences between console and winforms are within the noise.

**Code**

Identical code for both projects for the test

```
internal static bool IsPrimeTest(ulong num)
{
    if (num == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (ulong i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(num); i += 2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the runner

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    ulong x = 18446744073709551557ul;
    textBox1.Text = "Burn-in";
    Program.IsPrimeTest(x / 16);
    textBox1.Text = "Start timing";
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool ok = Program.IsPrimeTest(x);
    sw.Stop();
    string bits = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x32";
    textBox1.Text = $"Bits={bits}, Prime={ok}, Time={sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:f2} sec";
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

As fun side-note, a similar test with Intel Fortran produced `Time = 3.80 sec`, which is only  slightly faster than C#. Granted, Fortran does not support unsigned integers, so the checking had to happen with full precision floating point numbers. Each `mod(x,p)==0` call is translated into `x/p == int(x/p)`.

Comment: Uh, you're right. Turns out my WinForms was targeting .Net core while my console was targeting .Net framework. As usual, turns out the problem is that I'm an idiot :).

Comment: @puzzled a note to watch out is the [✅] Prefer 32-bit setting, which turns AnyCPU code into 32-bit code. This would occur a significant performance hit since you are dealing with 64-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: @puzzled - tried to be cute and port the above into Fortran only to realize that Fortran does not support unsigned integers and overflows with the above value.